# How to print selected features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, print-composer

I have a detailed map in qgis (vector, .shp) and I would like to split the map in four parts based on attributes to print each part of the map separately. Unfortunately, I didn't figure out how to do that, yet.

I can select the desired values (for one printout) in the attributes table and the region of the map gets highlighted. I could now save the selection as a new layer, reopen it, and print it. however, that doesn't seem to be the smart way, because i would end up with too many files.

I thought i could simply print only the selection. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to print a series of maps based on the data in a layer?

Comment: yes. andre's post showed me a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a query on the vector layer by right-clicking on it `-> Query`, filtering out the objects you don't want to see. By changing or deleting the query filter entry, you can create the other views, or full view again.

This does not change the shapefile itself, only the project file.

Comment: Thank you! your solution devliverd the desired result. i thought the "query" would work similar to selecting items from the attribute table, which just highlighted the appropriate cells. bu: it works delivers a different result. great! sorry for "editing" your text, didn't figure out how to use the "comment" functionality...